# Why orbital ellipse?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Of what exactly depends the eccentricity? I suppose that the smaller orbit its eccentricity will be greater, reason why it is closer to forming a circumference, but because the comment halley has great eccentricity, if it has a bigger orbit?

Comment: The eccentricity is the coefficient of variation between the maximum radius and the minimum radius (a and b) see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion

Comment: Im learning that, but i need the reazon

Comment: What do you mean by the reason? The eccentricity depends on the         semi-minor/major axis. The bigger the difference in these values, the bigger the eccentricity.

Comment: If you are asking "why do different planets, asteroids, and other gravitational orbital objects  have different eccentricities?" the short answer is  "they had different initial conditions when they began orbiting." To first order, the angular momentum and the mechanical energy remain constant. It is not singularly related to the size of the orbit.

Answer (score 3):

An object in orbit has two conserved quantities: energy and angular momentum.

These are independent (knowing the energy is not enough to know the angular momentum); this is why you need two parameters to describe the orbit. Either semi-major axis and eccentricity, or energy and angular momentum, can be used. Of course you could pick others - but always you have to pick two.